# Bootstrap CSS menu style and css styles not engaging on pages other than index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On Index all FONT STYLE AND COLOR AND "FLIPPING" MENU works fine, BUT on 7775.html in the page folder the menu is not flipping and font color is not being picked, but it was working a couple weeks ago.

I am confused as to why this works on the index.html, and not on my other page.

I would be very grateful if someone could spot what I am doing since I have looked at this far too long...advance thank you.

INDEX.HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

          <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

          <link title="no title" type="text/css"     href="css/main.css"rel="stylesheet" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
          <link title="no title" type="text/css" href="css/cssmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cssmenu.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>

          <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" h    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

          <!-- Optional theme -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <!--custom.css -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">

          <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond">
          <style>
          body {
            font-family: 'Cormorant+Garamond', serif;
            font-size: 48px;
              }
        </style>


        </head>

        <body>

        <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
`        <div class="col-sm-8">
           <h2>Works Great in blue as I want</h2>
           <h4>Showing the way I want it with blue font</h4>  
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

     <div class="container">
       <div id="cssmenu" class="dropdown">
        <ul>
         <li class="active"><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://www.fabulousprofessional.com">Northern Virginia Property Search</a></li>
         <li><a href="pages\7775.html">Featured Properties</a></li>
         <li><a href="pages\buyerssellers.html">Buyer and Seller Info</a>    </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
```

****ON File ../pages/7775.html: NOT PICKING UP COLOR in header elements and menu is merely shown as an ordered list and not flipping (3D) in the style and color of background of text I wish as in the index.html. Confused because it was working recently****

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

```
<link title="no title" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<link title="no title" type="text/css" href="css/cssmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cssmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">   </script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--custom.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond">

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Cormorant+Garamond', serif;
      font-size: 14px;
       }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <h2>NOT PICKING UP COLOR</h2>
    <h4>NOT PICKING UP COLOR</h4>
   </div>   
 </div>
</div>

  <div class="container">
     <div id="cssmenu" class="dropdown">
       <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.eblockhomes.com">Northern Virginia Property Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="pages\7775.html">Featured Properties</a></li>
   <li><a href="pages\buyerssellers.html">Buyer and Seller Info</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**> CSSStyleSHeets - main.css is as follows**

```
.jumbotron {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  color: inherit;
 }
.jumbotron .row img {
  border: 0 none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.jumbotron #name {
  width: 100%;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .jumbotron #name {
    width: 100%;
    height: 245px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.button #singlebutton.btn.btn-primary{
  background-image: #E9ECEF;
}

.item.active {
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item .active img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

ul {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.form-horizontal{
  float: right !important;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.lead{
  margin-top: 5px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 790px) {
  ul {
   display: inline-flex !important;
  }

.link {
  color:#ffffff;
}

h2 {
  color: #4d79ff;
}

div {
  color: #4d79ff;
}
body {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
p {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

**custom.css IS AS FOLLOWS**

```
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.page-header {
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
.col-sm-8 {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 120px;
  right: 0;
}
 .col-sm-4 {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0px;
}
.jumbotron.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.css-selector {
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
}

img {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

**cssmenu.css IS AS FOLLOWS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;

}

#cssmenu > ul {
  background: #4d79ff;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #4d79ff;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #dff2fa;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #1c799c;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -ms-transform: none;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  color: #1c799c;
  background: #19799f;
  content: attr(data-title);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(- -18px);
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a::before,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover::before {
  background: #4d79ff;
}

   #cssmenu.small-screen {
      width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu.small-screen > ul,
    #cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
    }

#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}

#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a::before {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #4d79ff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 17px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 22px;
  height: 3px;
}

    #cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
      border-top: 2px solid #81D9FB;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #81D9FB;
    }

    #cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      right: 20px;
      top: 27px;
       display: block;
      width: 22px;
      height: 2px;
      background: #ffffff;
    }

    #cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
      background: #81D9FB;
    }

#cssmenu.button.btn.btn-sm {
  border-top: 2px solid #45a7cc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #45a7cc;
}
```

NOW HERE IS JAVASCRIPT FOR MENU:

```
function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

    var cssmenu = $(this),
  settings = $.extend({
    title: "Menu",
    format: "dropdown",
    breakpoint: 768,
    sticky: false
  }, options);

return this.each(function() {
  cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
  if (settings.format != 'select') {
    cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
    $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
      var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
      if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
        mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
      } else {
        mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
        if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
          mainmenu.find('ul').show();
        }
      }
    });

    multiTg = function() {
      cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
      cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
        if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
          $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
        } else {
          $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
        }
      });
    };

    if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
    else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
  } else if (settings.format === 'select') {
    cssmenu.append('<select style="width: 100%"/>').addClass('select-list');
    var selectList = cssmenu.find('select');
    selectList.append('<option>' + settings.title + '</option>', {
      "selected": "selected",
      "value": ""
    });
    cssmenu.find('a').each(function() {
      var element = $(this),
        indentation = "";
      for (i = 1; i < element.parents('ul').length; i++) {
        indentation += '-';
      }
      selectList.append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' + indentation + element.text() + '</option');
    });
    selectList.on('change', function() {
      window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });
  }

  if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

  resizeFix = function() {
    if ($(window).width() > settings.breakpoint) {
      cssmenu.find('ul').show();
      cssmenu.removeClass('small-screen');
      if (settings.format === 'select') {
        cssmenu.find('select').hide();
      } else {
        cssmenu.find("#menu-button").removeClass("menu-opened");
      }
    }

    if ($(window).width() <= settings.breakpoint && !cssmenu.hasClass("small-screen")) {
      cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
      cssmenu.addClass('small-screen');
      if (settings.format === 'select') {
        cssmenu.find('select').show();
      }
    }
  };
  resizeFix();
  return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

});


};
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    format: "dropdown"
  });

  $("#cssmenu a").each(function() {
    var linkTitle = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr('data-title', linkTitle);
  });
});

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you show use some screens?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your file structure correctly, it looks like this

```
/
index.html
css/ FOLDER
    main.css
    cssmenu.css
js/ FOLDER
    cssmenu.js
    main.js
pages/ FOLDER
    7775.html
```

In this case, your index.html file can find your CSS and JavaScript files because your file paths are `css/main.css` and `js/cssmenu.js`, etc.

HOWEVER, because your `7775.html` file is in the `pages` folder and your file paths are the same, what it's actually looking for is a JS and a CSS folder within the `pages` folder.

All you have to do to get the `7775.html` page working is tell it to look in the parent directory first by adding `../` to your file paths.

This:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

becomes this:

```
<link type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cssmenu.js"></script>
```

becomes this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cssmenu.js"></script>
```

And so on...

---

(The links out to the main bootstrap styles, etc are all still working, though, because those links have a "absolute" file path that starts with `http://`)

Comment: Yes this works. I should have caught that....not sure why it worked before. It has been a few months since I looked at this. Thank you so very much. However it is still not picking up the background color of white on my <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="col-sm-8">

Comment: You forgot to close your media queries in your main.css file, so all of the rest of your CSS (even from other style sheets) would only be rendered if you met the conditions for that query.

Comment: Media queries start with `@media (QUERY){` and they end with `}`. See this jsfiddle that I made for you (comments in CSS): http://jsfiddle.net/Ly5ouc53/4